# View the command needed to locally checkout a pull request from a fork in the BitBucket interface?

Tags: bitbucket

Is it possible to view the command needed to locally (on my machine) checkout a pull request from a fork of the current repo in the BitBucket? I can't seem to figure out how to checkout the PR on my local machine. This is possible via the [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/) interface and I have done it in the past. I haven't been able to find a similar way of doing this with the BitBucket interface.

I found this: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/163739/what-is-the-url-of-a-pull-request which is disappointing. Perhaps things have changed? Does anyone know of a workaround?